# Cannot access values of object in ejs view

Tags: javascript, view, ejs, server-side-rendering

The following ejs view outputs `object` for `typeof()`.

```
  <% if(typeof msg !== 'undefined'){ %>
    <p><%- msg %> <%- typeof(user)  %> </p>   
  <% } %>
```

This will output the entire object in the view.

```
  <% if(typeof msg !== 'undefined'){ %>
    <p><%- msg %> <%- user  %> </p>   
  <% } %>
```

Like so,

```
{ _id: 6209571311be2a36444347fd, name: 'Joe', email: 'joe@e.com'}
```

However, when I try to access the values of `user` it results in either no output or an 'undefined' error.

For example, this code does not output the `user.name` value or throw any errors.

```
  <% if(typeof msg !== 'undefined'){ %>
     <p><%- msg %> <%- user.name  %></p>   
  <% } %>
```

While this code causes the 'Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'.

```
 <% if(typeof msg !== 'undefined'){ %>
   <p><%- msg %> <%- user[0]['name']  %></p>   
 <% } %>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: your last code anyway should be `user['name']`  since it is not an array. anyway tried to reproduce on https://ionicabizau.github.io/ejs-playground/ and seems to work

Comment: make sure your object isnt stringified either but i guess it is an object since typeof gave object

Comment: @cmgchess I tried `user['name]` also. Still doesn't work. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: btw how are you not gettng [object Object]

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. There's no reason the code here wouldn't work in and of itself. It has to be some other behavior or misunderstanding.